# Zabbix item name with Key-value

Tags: zabbix

I have created an item. There I execute a command via system.run, which gives me the name,status as a string from a Docker container.

Using preprocessing and REGEX I have separated the two values from one another. I return the second value as Value. This all works.

But now I want to bring the first parameter in the name of the item. In the docu, table it says that it worked with "$1" but not anymore. (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/item)

But currently it is possible to include macros in the name. Maybe this is a possibility?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading from zabbix 5.0 to 6.2

Comment: Another "me too" after upgrading from 5 to 6.2. Seems to have broken a lot of the naming using the stock templates, CPU parameters seem to be affected most. I've just started to go down the affected template items and manually rename them, its not too many. Would not be the first time Zabbix broke something like this and only got a single sentence mention in the changelog, so if you dont read those for *every.single.update* you get bit like this.